# When using display_rotate=1 the screen tears

Tags: hdmi, display

I'm trying to set the rotation on the Raspberry Pi to portrait mode. On startup the RPi GUI is shown looking fine but if I move anything (a window for example) then the screen tears (not fully repainting the background). I was wondering if this is connected to the monitor HDMI settings and I have tried several different options all to no avail. I followed the *WHICH VALUES ARE VALID FOR MY MONITOR?* instructions and the results are below. I also have the `edid.dat` file if anyone would find that useful.

I'm really stumped how to stop the screen tearing like this - needless to say this only happens when `display_rotate` are set to `1` or `3`.

Any ideas would be very welcome!

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 15 modes:
  (prefer) mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 6: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 7: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
  (native) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 21: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 22: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 10 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 8: 800x600 @ 56Hz 4:3, clock:36MHz progressive
           mode 9: 800x600 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:40MHz progressive
           mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:65MHz progressive
           mode 32: 1280x960 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:108MHz progressive
           mode 35: 1280x1024 @ 60Hz 5:4, clock:108MHz progressive
           mode 47: 1440x900 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:106MHz progressive
           mode 51: 1600x1200 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:162MHz progressive
           mode 58: 1680x1050 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:146MHz progressive
           mode 82: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state 0x12001a [HDMI CEA (1) RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

Comment: You could [try this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37305/5538); be sure to read the comments.  In case it's not clear, this means not setting any rotation in `config.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I just installed the latest firmware update and it fixed the problem!

Comment: Can you post that as an answer quickly?

Answer (score 1):

So seems I basically needed to update the firmware and this was the answer...

Comment: I updated the GPU firmware using `sudo rpi-update` but the tearing is still present on `display_rotate=3`. Did you do anything else?

Comment: @goldilocks sorry for bothering you, but James doesn't seem available. I have executed `sudo rpi-update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but nothing happened. Did I miss anything?