# Rotating Display on Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: pi-2, video

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B connected to a RIF6 projector via HDMI. My goal is to flip the video 180 degrees while the OS is running. I have researched this and found that `xrandr` should be the way to go. If I run

`DISPLAY=:0 xrandr`
It returns:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1136 x 592, current 1136 x 592, maximum 1136 x 592
default connected 1136x592+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1136x592        0.0*
```

This would seem to indicate the display 0 is the one I want to rotate.

I have tried many variants to this but I believe the proper command should be:

`sudo xrandr --output 0 --rotate left`

But the response I get is:

`Can't open display`

**OR** I have tried:
`DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output 0 --rotate left`

Which returns:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output 0 not found; ignoring
```

Has anybody successfully achieved rotating the video without restarting the RPi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure monitor to allow rotation](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37972/configure-monitor-to-allow-rotation)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. `xrandr` does not work as the display code is in the GPU. See [configure monitor to allow rotation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37972/8697) and an answer for what is possible.