# Rotate on an HDMI

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display

I have been trying to simply rotate the screen on my Raspberry Pi so it looks like portrait mode. I can't seem to figure out the problem. I go to

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

And then I added both the lines

```
lcd_rotate = 2 
display_rotate = 3
```

I have looked on all the forums and some say to use the first one and some say to use the second one. I have tried all different values and combinations to no avail. Please send help. Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried them seperately?

Comment: Yes I have but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config to rotate HDMI display is `display_rotate=3`

**SPACES** are significant! You **MUST** enter commands exactly as described in the documentation. Putting in spurious commands is also a bad idea. Unless you actually have a LCD screen don't include.

I use a script to rotate my screen; see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62147/8697